# Territory not assigned automatically on opportunity creation

Tags: apex, territory

Hi everyone I have this problem that when i try to create an opportunity the territory gets only shared with the creator of the opportunity and not also with the account/customer that i have inserted in opportunity

edit--

It was solved there was a check on equals an i put .toLowerCase() the variables that was in bigger Case.

Example

(GroupTerritory).equals(GROUP TERRITORY) \NOT SHARED TERRITORY

GroupTerritory.toLowerCase();
GROUPTERRITORY.toLowerCase();
(GroupTerritory).equals(GROUPTERRITORY) \SHARED TERRITORY

Comment: Have you checked the territory settings in Setup?  What is the current territory of the account, and who is in the territory?  Please [edit] your post to include more details and describe the troubleshooting you have already done.